# Powershell replace text on lines based on length

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I have a set of text files, which has following structure.

**Problem Statement** : Each Line could be 80 characters or less than 80. I want to remove any 8 digit numeric number if it is found at end of line, incase its length is 80 characters.

For example in below. Line 1 and Line 2 are 80 characters each with 8 digit numeric number at end. So simple remove last 8 digits i.e. 00100001 and 00100002. For Line 3 and Line 4, do nothing. For Line 5, again remove last 8 numeric digits i.e. 00100024. For Line 6, do nothing. P.S. Bracketed stuff (Length 80 Line 1) is just for illustration and is not part of any line.

```
ABCD   some text     00100001  (length 80 Line 1)
EFGH                 00100002  (Length 80 Line 2)
ABCD   Some text               (Length less than 80 Line 3)
XYZD                           (Length less than 80 Line 4)
MNOP                 00100024  (Length 80 Line 5)
ABCD                           (Length less than 80 Line 6)
```

**Result of above**

```
ABCD   some text     
EFGH                 
ABCD   Some text     
XYZD                 
MNOP                 
ABCD
```

---

So Far, I could only set-it up to read all files in loop but not able to actually change the contents of file. I am sure I have problem with out-file thing.

```
**
#ERROR REPORTING ALL
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$path     = "d:\users\desktop\D2d_Try"
$files    = Get-Childitem $path -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) }

    Function getStringMatch
    {
      # Loop through all *.txt files in the $path directory
      Foreach ($file In $files)
      {
       $content = Get-Content $file.fullName 

    $content | foreach-object { if($_.length -eq 80) { if($_ -match "^.{72}([0-9]{8})") 
    { 
    $_ -replace "$matches[1]"," " | out-file "c:\$file" -append
    }
    }
    }

    }
    }

    getStringMatch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many ways to approach this. One solution is:

```
#ERROR REPORTING ALL
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$path = "d:\users\desktop\D2d_Try"

#Creating function first.
#A function should not depend on a variable outside the function ($files in this case)
Function getStringMatch([System.IO.FileInfo]$File, $OutputPath)
{
    Get-Content $File.fullName | ForEach-Object { 
        #The following replace regex will remove the numbers if they are there and the length is 80, if not it will return it as it was.
        $_ -replace "^(.{72})([0-9]{8})$", '$1'
    } | Set-Content -Path (Join-Path $OutputPath $File.Name)
}


$files = Get-Childitem $path -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) } | % { getStringMatch -File $_ -OutputPath "C:\" }
```

If you also want to trim all lines to get rid of the extra whitespace at the start and end, you just need to change the `$_ -replace ...` line to:

```
($_ -replace "^(.{72})([0-9]{8})$", '$1').Trim()
```

To be honest I don't see why you need to match 80 chars if that's the only scenario where the 8digit ID is there. You could simply replace all 8digit IDs at the end of the string. To try it, replace the `$_ -replace ...` line in the sample above with:

```
$_ -replace '[0-9]{8}$'
```

Answer (score 1):

I did following and it seems to work :

```
#ERROR REPORTING ALL
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$path     = "d:\users\desktop\Cobol_D2d"
$files    = Get-Childitem $path -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) }

Function getStringMatch
{
  # Loop through all *.txt files in the $path directory
  Foreach ($file In $files)
  {
   (Get-Content $file.fullName) -replace '[0-9]{8}$',' ' | set-content $file.fullname 

}
}

getStringMatch
```

Comment: Since it would appear you used Frode F.'s answer it is appropriate that you mark it as the answer.